# PDE separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Hi could someone guide me this problem

It says ,

$ u_t - u_{xx}-2 u_x=0  $

Use the method of separation of variables to find all possible solutions.

Could someone help me out for this problem. I'm beginner at PDE. I would be much appreciated if you able to show some partial work so that I can understand.

Thanks in advance for taking my consideration

Comment: You know how to accept answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271053, but you don't know how to accept answer in this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case $1$: $\text{Re}(t)\geq0$

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)-X''(x)T(t)-2X'(x)T(t)=0$

$X(x)T'(t)=X''(x)T(t)+2X'(x)T(t)$

$X(x)T'(t)=(X''(x)+2X'(x))T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)+2X'(x)}{X(x)}=-(f(s))^2-1$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-(f(s))^2-1\\X''(x)+2X'(x)+((f(s))^2+1)X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{-t((f(s))^2+1)}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)e^{-x}\sin(xf(s))+c_2(s)e^{-x}\cos(xf(s))&\text{when}~f(s)\neq0\\c_1xe^{-x}+c_2e^{-x}&\text{when}~f(s)=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=C_1xe^{-x-t}+C_2e^{-x-t}+\int_sC_3(s)e^{-x-t((f(s))^2+1)}\sin(xf(s))~ds+\int_sC_4(s)e^{-x-t((f(s))^2+1)}\cos(xf(s))~ds~\text{or}~C_1xe^{-x-t}+C_2e^{-x-t}+\sum\limits_sC_3(s)e^{-x-t((f(s))^2+1)}\sin(xf(s))+\sum\limits_sC_4(s)e^{-x-t((f(s))^2+1)}\cos(xf(s))$

Case $2$: $\text{Re}(t)\leq0$

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)-X''(x)T(t)-2X'(x)T(t)=0$

$X(x)T'(t)=X''(x)T(t)+2X'(x)T(t)$

$X(x)T'(t)=(X''(x)+2X'(x))T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)+2X'(x)}{X(x)}=(f(s))^2-1$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=(f(s))^2-1\\X''(x)+2X'(x)+(1-(f(s))^2)X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{t((f(s))^2-1)}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)e^{-x}\sinh(xf(s))+c_2(s)e^{-x}\cosh(xf(s))&\text{when}~f(s)\neq0\\c_1xe^{-x}+c_2e^{-x}&\text{when}~f(s)=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=C_1xe^{-x-t}+C_2e^{-x-t}+\int_sC_3(s)e^{-x+t((f(s))^2-1)}\sinh(xf(s))~ds+\int_sC_4(s)e^{-x+t((f(s))^2-1)}\cosh(xf(s))~ds~\text{or}~C_1xe^{-x-t}+C_2e^{-x-t}+\sum\limits_sC_3(s)e^{-x+t((f(s))^2-1)}\sinh(xf(s))+\sum\limits_sC_4(s)e^{-x+t((f(s))^2-1)}\cosh(xf(s))$

Hence $u(x,t)=\begin{cases}C_1xe^{-x-t}+C_2e^{-x-t}+\int_sC_3(s)e^{-x-t((f(s))^2+1)}\sin(xf(s))~ds+\int_sC_4(s)e^{-x-t((f(s))^2+1)}\cos(xf(s))~ds&\text{when}~\text{Re}(t)\geq0\\C_1xe^{-x-t}+C_2e^{-x-t}+\int_sC_3(s)e^{-x+t((f(s))^2-1)}\sinh(xf(s))~ds+\int_sC_4(s)e^{-x+t((f(s))^2-1)}\cosh(xf(s))~ds&\text{when}~\text{Re}(t)\leq0\end{cases}$

or $\begin{cases}C_1xe^{-x-t}+C_2e^{-x-t}+\sum\limits_sC_3(s)e^{-x-t((f(s))^2+1)}\sin(xf(s))+\sum\limits_sC_4(s)e^{-x-t((f(s))^2+1)}\cos(xf(s))&\text{when}~\text{Re}(t)\geq0\\C_1xe^{-x-t}+C_2e^{-x-t}+\sum\limits_sC_3(s)e^{-x+t((f(s))^2-1)}\sinh(xf(s))+\sum\limits_sC_4(s)e^{-x+t((f(s))^2-1)}\cosh(xf(s))&\text{when}~\text{Re}(t)\leq0\end{cases}$

This is already the general solution of $u_t-u_{xx}-2u_x=0$ . Note that when without any I.C.s, the form of $f(s)$ can choose arbitrary, but when I.C.s are given, the form of $f(s)$ and the choice whether using the integration kernel or using the summation kernel should choose wisely in order to accommodate the I.C.s to get the most nice form of the solution, especially the number of I.C.s is more than two.

Comment: Thank you so much doraemonpaul!!!! You really save me. I'm glad you able to help me till the end. Thanks once again man!!

Comment: @Garett I want to make sure you know that on this site you can (and should) *accept* the best answers to your questions by clicking a checkmark to the left of the question. This serves multiple purposes, in particular it tells other readers that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 6):

If $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, then

$$\frac{T'}{T} = \frac{X''}{X} + 2 \frac{X'}{X}$$

LHS depends on $t$ only, RHS depends on $x$ only, so both sides are equal to a constant, say $\lambda$.  You can take it from here...

Comment: should i need to make $\lambda$ into 3 cases. Example let $\lambda$ = p^2(for positive), $\lambda$ = -p^2 (for negative), and $\lambda$ =0

Comment: Those 3 "cases" are all attempts to avoid imaginary numbers.  What is the equation modeling (e.g., harmonic motion with damping)?  What are the initial/boundary conditions?  These questions will guide you on the allowed values of $\lambda$.

Comment: The question didnt mention anything. It just ask me to solve. So what should I do ?

Comment: You cannot get a unique solution without some initial condition (in time) and boundary conditions (in space).  If not given, then a) make them up, or b) ask whoever asked the question.  Is this homework, or is it an actual problem you have encountered in, e.g., research?

Comment: In any case, if you can solve the individual ODE's, then you can construct a general solution.  Can you do this?

Comment: For X ODE part i'm stuck. X''(x)+2X'(x)-$\lambda$X(x)=0

Comment: Write $X(t) = A e^{r x}$, plug into equation, solve resulting quadratic ($r^2 + 2 r - \lambda = 0$) for $r$.  Get 2 solutions $r_1$ and $r_2$, general solution is $X(x) = A_1 e^{r_1 x} + A_2 e^{r_2 x}$.  $A_1$ and $A_2$ are constants determined by boundary conditions.

Comment: ok I understand but where is your lambda missing???

Comment: It's contained in the roots $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much rlgordonma for your help. You really helped me alot in this question. Once again thanks