# Separation of variables PDE problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Use separation of variables to solve the initial boundary value problem:
> $$u_t=u_{xx}+2u \cos(t)\quad\text{on}\quad x \in (0,\pi),\quad t>0,$$ $$u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0,$$ $$u(x,0)=\phi(x).$$

I look up this old post too get an idea, but I am still not sure how to treat the $2u \cos(t)$ part. [PDE separation of variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269746/pde-separation-of-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=T(t)X(x)$.  If you can get to

$ \displaystyle \frac{T_t}{T}-2\cos t = \frac{X_{xx}}{X}$

then both sides of the equation must be equal to the same *constant* $C$, and you can take it from there.